# How to vocally start app with parameter using Google Assistant?

Tags: actions-on-google

Currently, it's possible to open my app using Google Assistant by saying 
"Ok Google, open MyApp"

Is it possible to pass a parameter to my app's main activity ?

For exemple, if I say
"Ok Google, open MyApp action A"

Can I get the "action A" parameter in the intent given to my app's main activity ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say something like "talk to Resistance Decoder about a red, yellow, and blue resistor".

When this happens, your action is started but will skip the main intent. Instead, the rest of the phrase (a red, yellow, and blue resistor) will be sent to Dialogflow or Actions SDK and be processed as a different intent.

So the user will immediately get the answer they want.

It's referred to as a deep link intent: https://developers.google.com/actions/sdk/invocation-and-discovery#deep_link_invocation